# ngUpgrade - routing from ng2 to ng1 - how?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-ui-router, router

I am using ngUpgrade and I dont know how to handle the routing between ng2 and ng1. If I am in ng2 component, how do I route to ng1 controller? and viceversa.

I am using ui-router for the ng1. For ng2 I am using the router on the angular team.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 7):

First you need to have defined your routes as normal in both Angular 1.x and 2.x apps.

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

            // route for the home page
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
                controller  : 'mainController'
            })

            // route for the about page
            .when('/about', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
                controller  : 'aboutController'
            })

            // route for the contact page
            .when('/contact', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html',
                controller  : 'contactController'
            });
    });
```

And in the Angular 2 `Module`:

```
Module.config(($routeProvider) => {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/user/:id',     {template : '<user-details></userdetails>'})
    .when('/users', {template : '<user-list></userlist>'});
});
```

You can create a class called `Ng1Ng2UrlHandlingStrategy` and in there devide your routes between them:

```
class Ng1Ng2UrlHandlingStrategy implements UrlHandlingStrategy {
  shouldProcessUrl(url) { return url.toString().startsWith("/home") || url.toString().startsWith("/aboute") || url.toString().startsWith("/contact"); }
  extract(url) { return url; }
  merge(url, whole) { return url; }
}
```

And in your main component:

```
providers: [
    // Providing a custom url handling strategy to tell the Angular 2 router
    // which routes it is responsible for.
    { provide: UrlHandlingStrategy, useClass: Ng1Ng2UrlHandlingStrategy }
]
```

Finally, update the `root` component to include an Angular 2 router outlet.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'root-cmp',
  template: `
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <div class="ng-view"></div>
  `,
})
export class RootCmp {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. There is a missing part : how do I transfer states from ng2 to ng1? I am searching for the "$state.go" expression in the ng2 component.

Comment: That's the point, all the routes are handled by ng2 and that class is deciding which paths to handle and which to not, take a look at the logic at shouldProcessUrl

Comment: My shouldProcessUrl is always being called with '/' (never with the actual url I put in)